# How to decode this type of string in c#?

Tags: c#

In game,there is one file,where text is in strange type.
It must looks like

```
Test Skillbook
```

but it looks like `Test Ski䂌︍갑섃ñ` in Unicode.
In byte array it looks like

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 84, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 83, 0, 107, 0, 105, 0, 108, 240, 140, 64, 13, 254, 17, 172, 3, 193, 241,0 };
```

It may be encoded using LZ77.I tried to decode,but without success.
I know that there is not enough information,but i hope someone knows how to decode it)

Comment: What's the actual data in bytes?

Comment: You are right -- there is not enough information.  We can't just guess at the encoding based on the provided values.

Comment: @harold,added in first post.

Comment: Why do you think its LZ77 encryption? It doesn't look like this here.

Comment: In game core,there was talking about MPPC,but it's for http.

Comment: And normal byte array looks like byte[] b = new byte[] { 84, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 83, 0, 107, 0, 105, 0, 108, 240, 140, 64, 13, 254, 17, 172, 3, 193, 241,0 };

Comment: How do you have negative bytes in your C# array?

Comment: A file is one thing, but this is reminiscent of attempting to read a string from game memory. It's like what I have experienced before where you found a remnant of the string in memory, but the rest of the bytes have been overwritten with other data.

Comment: There is that file editor,it reads that binary file and shows normal string.

Comment: @TyCobb copied from Hex.//Replaced now.

Comment: This could simply be garbage left over from an earlier copy operation -- the first "l" is in there (108), then the rest of the bytes aren't characters. Gather more strings that look like this. If there aren't any, you're likely barking up the wrong tree. If there are, you have more clues. If there is compression at work, you won't be able to decompress if you don't know the compressor's parameters. Also check for things like stride/chunks -- does the string continue somewhere else maybe? Search for `0, 108, 0, 98, 0` etcetera.

Comment: For example if i change name in Editor to "abcdefghijklmn" ,it shows usually in Hex,but i change name where letter are repeated,it decompress.For example if i change to "TestTest",it wont show second Test in Hex.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert,all strings in file are showed in this type.